# How to layout records horizontally and vertically

Tags: php, cakephp, layout

I have a users table which I want to display like the Stack Overflow users page. So say display 5 records then take a new row, display 5 records, take a new row...

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Which aspect of doing this are you unclear about? How to build the control structure in PHP, how to output it  ... ?

Comment: I just want to know what technique people are using to achieve this. So I guess I would unclear about the whole process of displaying this. I have my data now I need to figure out how to achieve this within my foreach

Comment: Is this table a PHP array or an sql table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about something called pagination. You can achieve it by having a variable that indicated page number and based on it calculate which rows and from which one you will be displaying the data.

Comment: thanks it seems that cakephp has a pagination helper that i'll use

Comment: oh, i didn't see that you tagged it as cakephp - i personally use symfony, but yes, cake has this functionality too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something every X iterations you'll need the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%`

So, lets say you're using table rows and you want a new one every 5 items displayed. You'll basically have the items inside a `<tr>`, each one in its own `<td>`. Then, every 5 items you'll close the row and open a new one:

```
$str = <<< END
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
END;

$numItems = count($items) ;

for ($i = 0 ; $i < $numItems) ; $i++) {
    $currItem = $items[$i] ;
    $str .= "<td>$currItem</td>";

    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        $str .= "
        </tr>
        <tr>" ;
    }
}

$str .= "
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>" ;
```

Comment: Sorry I took so long, this looks good thanks! I'm going to try it out